# Pesquisa por data no MySQL não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, data, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho uma query em meu código PHP que estava funcionando normal, mas de repente parou de funcionar sem eu ter feito nenhum tipo de alteração.

```
SELECT * FROM comportamento_loja 
where ativado = 1 
and datahoje BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(data_inicial, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%d/%m/%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(data_final, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Testei direto no phpadmin que antes estava funcionando e também não funciona mais. Fiz um teste com esta outra query direto no phpadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM comportamento_loja 
where ativado = 1 
and 2018-07-05 BETWEEN (data_inicial) AND (data_final)
```

E não funciona, mas se eu colocar aspas na data funciona:

```
SELECT * FROM comportamento_loja 
where ativado = 1 
and '2018-07-05' BETWEEN (data_inicial) AND (data_final)
```

Então tentei usar esta query que funciona no PHP mas tambem não funciona, talvez porque o parâmetro esteja sem aspas, não sei. Já estou há dois dias me dedicando só a isto e nada, já tentei de várias formas e nada, será que alguém consegue uma solução para este problema?

Estou usando: Win7, wamp server, PHP versão 7, 5.7.14 - MySQL e também PDO, mas como eu disse todas as queries eu também testo no phpadmin e nada.

Este é meu código:

```
$data_atual = date("d/m/Y");  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comportamento_loja where ativado = 1 and ? BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(data_inicial, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%d/%m/%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(data_final, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%d/%m/%Y')

try {
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);            
    $stmt->execute($data_atual); 
    $comportamento = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo '<span class="box-error"><h5>Erro ao carregar comportamento_loja:' . '<span class="description-error">' .$error->getMessage(). '</span>' .'</span>';                   
}                           
$stmt = null;
```

Comment: Tem mesmo que usar o `STR_TO_DATE` por que você não envia a data em formato`y-m-d` direto?

Comment: na verdade não é necessário, é que esta foi a opção que deu certo quando fiz a query. desta forma: SELECT * FROM comportamento_loja where ativado = 1 and '2018-07-05' BETWEEN (data_inicial) AND (data_final),  no phpadmin da certo mas no php nao, pois não consigo passar a variavel com aspas, onde tá '2018-07-05' seria um parametro datahoje que irá substituir o ?

Comment: e aquela $data_atual dentro do $stmt é assim mesmo?

Comment: Poste a funçao toda que faz a consulta

Comment: Este é o código:  $data_atual = date("d/m/Y");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comportamento_loja where ativado = 1 and ? BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(data_inicial, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%d/%m/%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(data_final, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%d/%m/%Y')

try { $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data_atual); $comportamento = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); } catch(PDOException $error) { echo 'Erro ao carregar comportamento_loja:' . '' .$error->getMessage(). '' .'';
}
$stmt = null;   . O $data_atual irá substituir o sinal ?

Comment: Tente converter a data para o formato mysql (Y-m-d) e tire o DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Como as datas estão chegando?

Comment: Tente fechar a string da variavel $sql = " SELECT ....  "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu percebi olhando o seu código que as aspas do $sql não está fechado

E vi que no execute tem um parâmetro, geralmente não tem.

Segue minha sugestão:

Um arquivo chamado **class.dao.php**

```html
class Dao
  {
   public function getDatas($data_inicial, $data_final){
        $this->connection = null;
        $this->connection = new ConnectionFactory();
        $row = array();
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM comportamento_loja 
               WHERE ativado = 1 
                 AND colunaData BETWEEN :data_inicial AND :data_final";

            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(":data_inicial", $data_inicial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":data_final", $data_final, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->connection = null;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo "Erro: ".$ex->getMessage();
        }
        return $row;
    }
```

E num arquivo anterior você instancia-o

```html
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 
  include 'class.dao.php';

  $dao = new Dao();
  $data1 = '2015-10-30';
  $data2 = '2018-07-30';
  
  $retorno = $dao->getDatas($data1, $data2 );
  $return = array_values($retorno);
  echo json_encode($return);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($retorno);
  echo "</pre>";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Obrigado adventistaam ficou perfeito é era isto mesmo. O código final ficou da seguinte forma:**

```
$data_atual = date("Y/m/d");  
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$hora_atual = date('H:i:s');                


$sql = "SELECT * 
              FROM comportamento_loja 
             WHERE ativado = 1 

             AND :data_atual BETWEEN data_inicial AND data_final
             AND :hora_atual BETWEEN hora_inicial AND hora_final";
try {
 $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);           
 $stmt->bindValue(":data_atual", $data_atual, PDO::PARAM_STR);            
 $stmt->bindValue(":hora_atual", $hora_atual, PDO::PARAM_STR);          
 $stmt->execute(); 
 $comportamento = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $error) {
echo '<span class="box-error"><h5>Erro ao carregar comportamento_loja:' . '<span class="description-error">' .$error->getMessage(). '</span>' .'</span>';                   
}                           
$stmt = null;
```

**Estas 03 linhas foram a solução do problema:**

```
$stmt->bindValue(":data_atual", $data_atual, PDO::PARAM_STR);            
$stmt->bindValue(":hora_atual", $hora_atual, PDO::PARAM_STR);          
$stmt->execute();
```

Valeu!!